# How to find value from a Dictionary<int, IEnumerable<Struct>>

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary, lambda

I have a dictionary, `salaryFitmentDictionary` which I would like to query (linq or lambda) based on example: where `employeedId = 1` and `EarningDeductionId = 145` and get the value of the balance, `EDBalance`.

How would I achieve this?

```
var balance = salaryFitmentDictionary.Where...

Dictionary<int, IEnumerable<SalaryFitmentInfoMonth>> salaryFitmentDictionary = new Dictionary<int, IEnumerable<SalaryFitmentInfoMonth>>();

employeeIdList.ToList().ForEach(employeedId =>
{
    var perEmployeeFitments = from pf in _db.PayFitments.AsEnumerable()
                              join ed in _db.EarningDeductions.AsEnumerable()
                              on pf.EarningDeductionId equals ed.EarningDeductionId
                              where pf.EmployeeId == employeedId
                              select new SalaryFitmentInfoMonth
                              {
                                   EDId = pf.EarningDeductionId,
                                   EDAmount = pf.Amount,
                                   EDBalance = pf.Balance.GetValueOrDefault(),
                                   EDType = ed.EDType,
                                   IsTaxable = ed.IsTaxable,
                                   IsBenefit = ed.IsBenefit,
                                   IsLoan = ed.IsLoan,
                                   IsAdvance = ed.IsAdvance,
                                   Limit = ed.TaxIfMoreThan.GetValueOrDefault()
                              };

    salaryFitmentDictionary.Add(employeedId, perEmployeeFitments);
});

public struct SalaryFitmentInfoMonth
{
    public int EDId { get; set; }
    public decimal EDAmount { get; set; }
    public decimal? EDBalance { get; set; }
    public EarnDeduct EDType { get; set; }
    public bool IsTaxable { get; set; }
    public bool IsBenefit { get; set; }
    public bool IsLoan { get; set; }
    public bool IsAdvance { get; set; }
    public decimal? Limit { get; set; }
 }
```

Comment: `ToList().ForEach` ಠ_ಠ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
IEnumerable<SalaryFitmentInfoMonth> salaries = salaryFitmentDictionary[1];
SalaryFitmentInfoMonth salary = salaries.FirstOrDefault(s => s.EDId == 45);
```

You should handle the case that `salaryFitmentDictionary` doesn't contain one with this ID. So you could use `TryGetValue` instead. If no salary has this `EDId` `FirstOrDefault` returns null.

So  here's the safer version:

```
IEnumerable<SalaryFitmentInfoMonth> salaries;
if(salaryFitmentDictionary.TryGetValue(1, out salaries))
{
    SalaryFitmentInfoMonth salary = salaries.FirstOrDefault(s => s.EDId == 45);
    if(salary != null) 
    {
        // do something ...
    }
}
```

If you expect more than one match you could use `Enumerable.Where` instead of `FirstOrDefault`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [SelectMany](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534336(v=vs.100).aspx) method in LINQ method syntax:

```
Int32 id = 1;
Int32 edId = 147;

var result = salaryFitmentDictionary.
    Where((pair) => pair.Key == id ).
    SelectMany((pair) =>
        pair.Value.Where((perEmployeeFitment) => perEmployeeFitment.EDId == edId)).
    Select(perEmployeeFitment => perEmployeeFitment.EDBalance).
    Single();
```

Or in query syntax:

```
Int32 id = 1;
Int32 edId = 147;

var result = (from pair in salaryFitmentDictionary
    from perEmployeeFitment in pair.Value
    where pair.Key == id
    where perEmployeeFitment.EDId == edId
    select perEmployeeFitment.EDBalance).Single();
```